# Creating breadcrumbs in symfony 2.1 using knpmenu bundle

Tags: php, symfony, navigation, breadcrumbs, knpmenubundle

What's the best way to create breadcrumbs using knpmenu bundle in symfony 2.1.x ? Aside from using 3-rd party bundles.

**UPDATE:**

Hi, **theunraveler**, sorry for late answer. Now I've been following your example and I'm stuck at one moment. Here, code below throws an exception, that

```
Missing argument 2 for Acme\DemoBundle\Menu\MenuBuilder::getBreadCrumbs()    

{% set item = knp_menu_get('main') %}
{{ knp_menu_render(item) }}
{% block breadcrumbs %}
    {% set breadcrumbs = knp_menu_get('breadcrumbs', [], {'request':    app.request, 'menu': item }) %}
    {{ dump(breadcrumbs) }}
{% endblock %}
```

Why it doesn't accepts "item" variable?

Comment: well, the `KnpMenuBundle` is a 3rd party bundle...

Comment: Agree, but what I meant is, do not add any more bundles when there's already an opportunity to create breadcrumbs in existing knpmenu bundle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Knp\Menu\MenuItem` class has a `getBreadcrumbsArray()` method. It should return an array of items in the current active menu trail. If you are on an earlier version of `KnpMenu` (<= 1.1.2, I think), the returned array will be in the form of `label => uri`. Otherwise, it will be an array with each item having keys `label`, `uri`, and `item`.

To find the current menu item, you'll probably want to create a method in your controller (or somewhere else, if it makes more sense for your project) that looks something like this:

```
public function getCurrentMenuItem($menu)
{
    foreach ($menu as $item) {
        if ($item->isCurrent()) {
            return $item;
        }

        if ($item->getChildren() && $current_child = $this->getCurrentMenuItem($item)) {
            return $current_child;
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

From there, you can call `getBreadcrumbsArray()` on the returned value:

```
$this->getCurrentMenuItem($your_menu)->getBreadcrumbsArray();
```

I guess what I would do ultimately is [create a Twig extension](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/advanced.html#creating-extensions) that registers a `breadcrumbs` global, and put the `getCurrentMenuItem()` method in there. That way, you can have the `breadcrumb` variable in all of your templates without having to manually render it in each controller.

Source: https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpMenu/blob/master/src/Knp/Menu/MenuItem.php#L544.

Comment: can you please provide some example of usage of this method? Because the problem lays on determining current item of the rendered menu.

Comment: Updated my answer with an example of how to find the current menu item.

Comment: getBreadcrumbsArray() is not availlable anymore. Do you know what to use instead?

Comment: @Netbulae, this method has been moved to `Knp\Menu\Util\MenuManipulator` see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28851780/1055200

Answer (score 10):

Since version `2.0`, `getBreadcrumbsArray` has been moved to `Knp\Menu\Util\MenuManipulator`.

Possible workout to [this](https://gist.github.com/Korpch/4183696) solution is to create a twig extension:

```
<?php

namespace Kimwild\CommonBundle\Twig;
use Knp\Menu\Util\MenuManipulator;
use Knp\Menu\ItemInterface;

class MenuManipulatorExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{

    public function getFunctions()
    {
        return array(
            new \Twig_SimpleFunction('menu_manipulator', array($this, 'menuManipulator')),
        );
    }

    public function menuManipulator(ItemInterface $item)
    {
        $manipulator = new MenuManipulator();
        return $manipulator->getBreadcrumbsArray($item);
    }


    public function getName()
    {
        return 'menu_manipulator';
    }

}
```

Register twig extension:

```
kimwild_common.menu_manipulator_extension:
    class: Kimwild\CommonBundle\Twig\MenuManipulatorExtension
    public: false
    tags:
        - { name: twig.extension }
```

In breadcrumb.html.twig:

```
{% block root %}
    {%- for  link in menu_manipulator(item) %}
    /* whatever you want to do ... */
    {%- endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: From 2012 up to now (2015) this has actually become the *right* answer on how to fix this issue in a **Symfony 2-friendly** way, deprecating the previously accepted one!

Answer (score 2):

Since KnpMenu `2.1`, there is a new twig function: `knp_menu_get_breadcrumbs_array`

You can take a look at my gist: https://gist.github.com/fsevestre/b378606c4fd23814278a

I added a new twig function `knp_menu_get_current_item`, which retrieve the current menu item and work fine with the `knp_menu_get_breadcrumbs_array` function.

--

Edit:

With KnpMenu `2.2`, you can now do:

```
<ol class="breadcrumb">
{% for breadcrumb_item in knp_menu_get_breadcrumbs_array(knp_menu_get_current_item('main')) %}
    {% if not loop.last %}
    <li><a href="{{ breadcrumb_item.uri }}">{{ breadcrumb_item.label }}</a></li>
    {% else %}
    <li class="active">{{ breadcrumb_item.label }}</li>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
</ol>
```

https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpMenu/blob/master/doc/02-Twig-Integration.markdown#functions

The `knp_menu_get_current_item('main')` Twig function will retrieve the current menu item, for the `main` menu.